# Rank by calculated variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql

The following table is for practice only. I will use the code on a much larger table.

```
SELECT *
FROM price_practice;
```

gives

```
 id   company       dt       price
'16', 'Amex', '2015-07-01', '5.00'
'17', 'Amex', '2015-07-02', '5.10'
'18', 'Amex', '2015-07-03', '5.00'
'19', 'Amex', '2015-07-06', '5.88'
'20', 'Amex', '2015-07-07', '4.21'
'21', 'Citi', '2015-07-01', '1.00'
'22', 'Citi', '2015-07-02', '1.10'
'23', 'Citi', '2015-07-03', '1.00'
'24', 'Citi', '2015-07-06', '0.88'
'25', 'Citi', '2015-07-07', '1.01'
'26', 'Amex', '2015-07-08', '5.23'
'27', 'Amex', '2015-07-09', '5.35'
'28', 'Amex', '2015-07-10', '5.55'
'29', 'Amex', '2015-07-13', '5.88'
'30', 'Amex', '2015-07-14', '6.01'
'31', 'Citi', '2015-07-08', '0.95'
'32', 'Citi', '2015-07-09', '0.83'
'33', 'Citi', '2015-07-10', '0.79'
'34', 'Citi', '2015-07-13', '0.72'
'35', 'Citi', '2015-07-14', '0.59'
```

The following snippet calculates the percentage change in price from one date to the next.

```
SELECT x.id, x.company, x.dt, x.price, (x.price - y.price)/y.price AS 'Change'
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.id AS aid, MAX(b.id) AS aPrevid
    FROM price_practice a
    INNER JOIN price_practice b
    WHERE a.id > b.id
    AND a.company = b.company
    GROUP BY a.id
) Sub1
INNER JOIN price_practice x ON Sub1.aid = x.id
INNER JOIN price_practice y ON Sub1.aPrevid = y.id
ORDER BY x.id DESC
```

As intended, it returns

```
 id   company       dt       price      Change
'35', 'Citi', '2015-07-14', '0.59', '-0.180556'
'34', 'Citi', '2015-07-13', '0.72', '-0.088608'
'33', 'Citi', '2015-07-10', '0.79', '-0.048193'
'32', 'Citi', '2015-07-09', '0.83', '-0.126316'
'31', 'Citi', '2015-07-08', '0.95', '-0.059406'
'30', 'Amex', '2015-07-14', '6.01', '0.022109'
'29', 'Amex', '2015-07-13', '5.88', '0.059459'
'28', 'Amex', '2015-07-10', '5.55', '0.037383'
'27', 'Amex', '2015-07-09', '5.35', '0.022945'
'26', 'Amex', '2015-07-08', '5.23', '0.242280'
'25', 'Citi', '2015-07-07', '1.01', '0.147727'
'24', 'Citi', '2015-07-06', '0.88', '-0.120000'
'23', 'Citi', '2015-07-03', '1.00', '-0.090909'
'22', 'Citi', '2015-07-02', '1.10', '0.100000'
'20', 'Amex', '2015-07-07', '4.21', '-0.284014'
'19', 'Amex', '2015-07-06', '5.88', '0.176000'
'18', 'Amex', '2015-07-03', '5.00', '-0.019608'
'17', 'Amex', '2015-07-02', '5.10', '0.020000'
```

The following snippet does something entirely different: it ranks observations by price for every company seperately.

```
SELECT    ( 
            CASE company 
            WHEN @curType 
            THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
            ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := company END
          ) + 1 AS rank,
          id,
          company,
          dt,
          price
FROM      price_practice,
          (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
ORDER BY  company DESC, price DESC;
```

As intended, it returns

```
rank  id   company       dt       price
'1', '22', 'Citi', '2015-07-02', '1.10'
'2', '25', 'Citi', '2015-07-07', '1.01'
'3', '23', 'Citi', '2015-07-03', '1.00'
'4', '21', 'Citi', '2015-07-01', '1.00'
'5', '31', 'Citi', '2015-07-08', '0.95'
'6', '24', 'Citi', '2015-07-06', '0.88'
'7', '32', 'Citi', '2015-07-09', '0.83'
'8', '33', 'Citi', '2015-07-10', '0.79'
'9', '34', 'Citi', '2015-07-13', '0.72'
'10', '35', 'Citi', '2015-07-14', '0.59'
'1', '30', 'Amex', '2015-07-14', '6.01'
'2', '19', 'Amex', '2015-07-06', '5.88'
'3', '29', 'Amex', '2015-07-13', '5.88'
'4', '28', 'Amex', '2015-07-10', '5.55'
'5', '27', 'Amex', '2015-07-09', '5.35'
'6', '26', 'Amex', '2015-07-08', '5.23'
'7', '17', 'Amex', '2015-07-02', '5.10'
'8', '18', 'Amex', '2015-07-03', '5.00'
'9', '16', 'Amex', '2015-07-01', '5.00'
'10', '20', 'Amex', '2015-07-07', '4.21'
```

**The question is:**

*How do I rank observations by percentage change?*

I imagine you can save the percentage change data in a new column and then rank it, but I suspect this is not the best method. I will do many similar calculations (eg weekly % change, variance etc), and I have around 3,000,000 observations, so the table would grow big quickly. If this is the only way to do it, I will, but I think combining the two snippets above to calculate percentage change and rank in one go would be better. Or what do you think?

As I'm sure you can tell from my question, I'm a beginner at MySQL. Any advise on how to proceed is appreciated!

Comment: In your first query, couldn't you use the same `CASE WHEN` statement that you're using in your second query? Just change the ORDER BY to `ORDER BY company DESC, Change DESC`?

Comment: I tried changing to `ORDER BY company DESC, Change DESC` and for some reason it sorts by company but not by Change. Even if it worked, this would not assign rankings as numerical values for each observation, which is what I need. So I would also have to insert the `CASE WHEN` statement into the first query, but I wouldn't know where or how to insert it. It doesn't seem to be as simple as replacing a variable or a single line of code.